# mongodb replicate-set with 3 servers but only 2 locations

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 x mongodb nodes configured as one shard (1 x primary and 2 x secondary) but I only have 2 data centers. If I host 1 x node in DataCenterA and 2 x nodes in DataCenterB and DataCenterB is down. Can I have anyway to get the node in DataCenterA to perform both read write instead of in read-only mode and once other nodes are back online the clusters can be retained?

Understand that the best practice is to have a third location to host each of node in one location but if I only have 2 x locations available do I have any way to make this option work?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by removing the node in data center A from the replica set and starting it back as a standalone node. You can add the node back once the other servers in the replica set are up.